# Confusion over output of encapsulation method code in Python

Tags: python, oop, methods, private, encapsulation

```
    class encap:
          __a = 10
          b=11
          def __abc(self):
              print(self.b)
              print(self.__a)
          def xyz (self):
              # calling private method 
              self.__abc()

    a1= encap()
    print(a1.xyz())
```

Here __a and __abc are private. So I am calling __abc() in xyz() method. Getting the output as

```
11
10
None
```

I understand about getting 11 and 10 but why should I got None as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are `print`ing the *result* of `a1.xyz()`, which returns `None` (because there is no `return` statement in `encap.xyz`). Simply calling `a1.xyz()` will be enough to print what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

By default, a method in Python returns `None` if you return nothing from it.

You can validate the same from the below code:

```
def test():
    print('Hello, world!')

print(test())
```

Output:

```
Hello, world!
None
```